# ui-router view is always same if I try new route while previous not resolved

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a menu with `ui-sref` on items.

If I click on menu route '1', then click on menu route '2' before route '1' is resolved, then the view of route '2' gets stuck:

Now I click on menu item '3'. I see in 'Networks' tab  of Chrome that route '3' is resolved. The url is changed to that of route '3'. But in `ui-view` the view of route '2' is still loaded.

`$stateChangeError` event does not fire. Console is clear.

Here is an example of my component based routes:

```
.state('main-app.sequences-mails', {
        url: '/sequences/mails',
        component: 'mailsComponent',
        resolve: {
            mailsData: ['Outbox', function(Outbox) {
                return Outbox.filter({
                    cat: 'inbox',
                    per_page: defaultSettings.perPage,
                }).$promise;
            }],
        }
    })
    .state('main-app.sequences-mails-dialog', {
        url: '/sequences/mails/{id:int}',
        component: 'emailDialogComponent',
        resolve: {
            boxData: ['Outbox', '$stateParams', function(Outbox, $stateParams) {
                return Outbox.get({ id: $stateParams.id }).$promise;
            }],
        }
    })
```

Comment: Edgar, could you provide some code so that we can go through it and help you out?

Comment: Create a demo that reproduces this. Can use `$timeout()` to create long resolve time as it also returns a promise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was ui-router old version bug